# Getting Country name By Ip Address in android

Tags: android, maxmind, ip-geolocation, country-codes

My requirement is to get country name by device Ip. Without any WEB/API calls. I googled well but I cannot conclude anything. We have good free service MaxMind but it provides CSV format as well its very huge in file size. Do we have any suggested way.? We should not use location based service like GPS/Network Provider..?

please helps me to fix this out..

Answer (score 6):

You can use
http://freegeoip.net/

It allows up to **10,000 queries** per hour by default.

It uses json parsing you can easily implement

**For ex:**
http://freegeoip.net/json/github.com

gives this

```
{"ip":"192.30.252.130","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","region_code":"CA","region_name":"California","city":"San Francisco","zip_code":"94107","time_zone":"America/Los_Angeles","latitude":37.77,"longitude":-122.394,"metro_code":807}
```

with **Country Code** and **Country Name**

Comment: Yes its free plus 10,000 requests per hour.

Comment: yes 100% I have tested it. You can also check ites accuracy by filling your ip in the url :  http://freegeoip.net/json/<your_ip_here>

Comment: this website is shutted down!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider IPInfoDB API http://www.ipinfodb.com

It is fast API using data delivery network (DDN). It allows 2 connections per second by default.

http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=your_api_key&ip=74.125.45.100

Answer (score 0):

Check this service. it is completely free:

https://iplist.cc/api

Comment: This API does not work correctly. I'm in Vietnam, but the returned country code is the US.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://ipstack.com/

http://freegeoip.net/ is change to http://freegeoip.net/
is very simple and useful.
Its implementation with volley in android is very easy