# How to get country code and Country name using IP

Tags: java, android

Im new for android, I want to get country name and country code using ip address. Please anyone guide me.

Below code for getting IP:

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled()) {
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
        int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
        String wifiIpAddress = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d",
                (ip & 0xff),
                (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
                (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
                (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

        return wifiIpAddress;
    }else{
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    Log.i("","111 inetAddress.getHostAddress(): "+inetAddress.getHostAddress());
                    //the condition after && is missing in your snippet, checking instance of inetAddress
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                        Log.i("","111 return inetAddress.getHostAddress(): "+inetAddress.getHostAddress());
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I dont know how to get country code and name using IP address.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If not necessary to find Country code and name from IP address than the best way to find  based on SIM or Network

Comment: If not use sim(Tablet) means.. What  i do... How to find

Comment: hope it helps you... http://stackoverflow.com/q/33516266/6334037

Answer (score 5):

1.) query your public ip-address:

```
public static String getPublicIP() throws IOException
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.checkip.org").get();
        return doc.getElementById("yourip").select("h1").first().select("span").text();
    }
```

2.) Then query your country code/name: (by using the method above)

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://ipinfo.io/"+getPublicIP());
HttpResponse response;
try {
    response = client.execute(request);

    Log.d("Response of GET request", response.toString());
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: there any free ip geo location with response json ?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this perfect guide: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-find-location-using-ip-address/

```
  //ip address something like that 192.168.0.1
  public String getCountryFromIP(String ipAddress) {

    File file = new File("resources/GeoLiteCity.dat");

    LookupService lookup = new LookupService(file,LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
    Location locationServices = lookup.getLocation(ipAddress);

    return locationServices.countryName;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way than using third-party APIs and the frequently outdated GeoLiteCity database.

Check the [ip2asn2cc](https://github.com/AxLabs/ip2asn2cc) library.

This library uses official databases provided by all [Regional Internet Registries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry), which are frequently updated.

I was using APIs for this purpose in the past, and my service was hitting API rate limits very frequently. IMHO, [ip2asn2cc](https://github.com/AxLabs/ip2asn2cc) provides more flexibility and cuts out external dependencies out of applications.

Comment: This library looks interesting, but there is no real documentation. Looking through the code it seems like it only lets you set a list of included or excluded country codes to filter against. It won't give you general info about what country code an IP maps to.

Comment: @idolize it does and it's super simple to use! ip2asn2cc fetches an updated list from RIR (Regional Internet Registries), where there's a list of subnets and their respective countries (allocation). You can see how to use ip2asn2cc by checking the tests here: https://github.com/AxLabs/ip2asn2cc/blob/master/src/test/java/com/axlabs/ip2asn2cc/Ip2Asn2CcIncludeFilterPolicyTest.java#L26-L33

Answer (score 0):

First you should get external IP address of the device, and then use some  web API [like this](http://freegeoip.net/)  to get country code and name.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my application I have same requirement to get user location based on ip address, as in android phone we can not get the external IP address. So we implement it at our server side by implementing web service. Through our web service we were able to get the user external ip address and then we used Maxmind API to get user country code and name. Maxmind Api's are paid but easy to implement.